# How to make a grid column the same height as the element above it and pushed left

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material UI and I have a grid sitting on top of a Paper element. The first column in the grid is a text input field that I'd to be the same height as the paper and I'd like it pushed left so that it shares the left border with the paper element but I'm not sure how to achieve this affect, I've tried setting 0 margins, changing the position, and messing with the height and width to no affect.

Code pen: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-ardinghelli-7cutft?file=/src/App.js

code

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

export default function ComplexGrid() {
  return (
    <Paper
      sx={{
        p: 2,
        margin: "auto",
        maxWidth: 500,
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#1A2027"
      }}
    >
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label=""
              variant="outlined"
              sx={{
                backgroundColor: "white",
                padding: "0",
                flex: 0
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid sx={{ alignSelf: "flex-end", color: "white" }} item xs={6}>
            <span>test v. test</span>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

edit: I found that if I disable padding-left for all the classes MuiGrid-root.Muigrid-item in inspect element it will push it to the left, but I only want to disable the padding for this first grid item. Overriding it with `sx={{paddingLeft: 0}}` doesn't seem to do anything

edit2: setting `sx={{paddingLeft: "0 !important", paddingTop: "0 !important"}}` has gotten the position I wanted, now I just want it to stretch to the size of the paper

Answer (score 0):

The `padding: 2` on my paper was the issue, removing this gave me a text input field the same size as my paper